# Numba performances

Tags: python, numba

I use a lot numba's `jit` decorator and I recently realize that new features have been added to numba, in particular `parallel` option and `stencil` decorator.

Stencil is very nice for making cleaner code, but after a few tests, it seems that it is just beautiful, not efficient. Here is a sample code :

```
@numba.njit
def nb_jit(A, out):
    for i in range(1, A.shape[0]-1):
         out[i] = 0.5*(A[i+1] - A[i-1])
    return out

@numba.njit(numba.float64[:](numba.float64[:], numba.float64[:]))
def nb_jit_typed(A, out):
    for i in range(1, A.shape[0]-1):
        out[i] = 0.5*(A[i+1] - A[i-1])
    return out

@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def nb_jit_paral(A, out):
    for i in numba.prange(1, A.shape[0]-1):
        out[i] = 0.5*(A[i+1] - A[i-1])
    return out

@numba.stencil
def s2(A):
    return 0.5*(A[1] - A[-1])

@numba.njit
def nb_stencil(A):
    return s2(A)

@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def nb_stencil_paral(A):
    return s2(A)
```

I tested these functions with the following arrays :

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(100000)
res = arr.copy()
```

and it gives me the following execution times (Of course, I executed each function one time before the timeit !):

---

```
____________________________________________________
| %timeit nb_jit(arr, res)           |   36 us     |
| %timeit nb_jit_typed(arr, res)     |   68 us     |
| %timeit nb_jit_paral(arr, res)     |  151 us     |
| %timeit nb_stencil(arr)            |   59 us     |
| %timeit nb_stencil_paral(arr)      |  241 us     |
____________________________________________________
```

So I was wondering :

- Why `nb_jit_typed` is slower than `nb_jit` ? In my memory, it was the opposite last time I tested this.
- Why `nb_jit_parallel` is so slow ?
- Did I use stencil correctly ? I mean, using stencil this way leads to a loss of performance, so why should we use it ?

---

---

**Note :**

```
import numba
numba.__version__
```

**'0.37.0'**

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

**4**

---

---

**Edit:**

Timing the same functions over 10000 repetitions with arrays of dimensions (1000000, ) with time.time() (without any GUI) :

```
jit             | 16.37 s
jit typed       | 17.22 s
jit parallel    | 18.45 s
stencil         | 21.95 s
stencil paral   | 24.48 s
```

Comment: Yes,**`numba`** is a great tool. Yet, how well do you isolate your tests from intervening O/S + GUI operations? Could you re-test the same via some non-GUI tool + having some decent 1E+3 test-repetitions, so as to see rather a wider population of results, than just an accidental spot into a one code-execution example biased by the test-exogenous influences from the outer ecosystem?

Comment: Was there any particular reason or rationale to still keep the decorated Functions-under-Test in an **expensive**, python-interoperable mode, without better striding-tricks and an explicit setting of **`nogil = True, nopython = True`** ?

Comment: I use `@njit`, which is the same as `@jit(nopython=True)`.

Comment: @njit(fastmath=True) is often also worth a try

Comment: **Why nb_jit_parallel is so slow?** The loop isn't simd-vectorized with Numba 0.37 if parallel=true. This should change with version 0.38 which is released soon. https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/2727